# .htaccess treat first segment in URL as $_GET parameter for all php files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The problem I'm facing with .htaccess is that I want to pass the first segment of URL as a $_GET parameter so that for example **www.example.com/en/** reads as **www.example.com?language=en** and **www.example.com/category/groceries/?language=en** reads as **www.example.com/en/category/groceries** , i want this to be done for all php pages without writing a rule for every page 
here is what i tried without success

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^en$ ?language=en&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^ar$ ?language=ar&%{QUERY_STRING} [NC,L,QSA]
```

However this doesn't work as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this single rule for all the URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If you want to support only `en` as language identifier then use:

```
RewriteRule ^(en)(/.*)?$ $2?language=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks ! , How can i support only two languages i.e ar and en , else redirect to en ?

Comment: For that use: `RewriteRule ^(?:en|ar)(/.*)?$ $1?language=en [L,QSA]`

Comment: it works fine if use en or ar , but if i use fr it shows error , i want to redirect to en instead in that case , Thank again !

Comment: Then 1st rule is better: `RewriteRule ^(?:[a-z]{2})(/.*)?$ $1?language=en [L,QSA]`